# Access denied message when I use - serverStatus command -- WAS V8,

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere

I am using Win7 system, I tried to stat my profile server in RAD8. It didn't start. I tried to start from command.

C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\bin>serverStatus -help

Access is denied.

!SESSION 2015-02-08 06:06:47.737 -----------------------------------------------

eclipse.buildId=M20060921-0945 java.fullversion=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.6 Windows 7 amd64-64 20110418_80450 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)

J9VM - R26_Java626_GA_FP1_20110418_1915_B80450

JIT  - r11_20110215_18645ifx8

GC   - R26_Java626_GA_FP1_20110418_1915_B80450

J9CL - 20110418_80450

BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US

Framework arguments:  -application com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher

Command-line arguments:  -application com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-02-08 06:06:48.510

!MESSAGE Error reading configuration: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServerprofiles\AppSrv1\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi.manager.fileTableLock (Access is denied.)

!STACK 0

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi.manager.fileTableLock (Access is denied.)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.Locker_JavaNio.lock(Locker_JavaNio.java:33)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.lock(StorageManager.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:688)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initFileManager(BaseStorage.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initialize(BaseStorage.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.initialize(Framework.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.(Framework.java:157)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:286)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:175)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:371)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:141)

C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\bin>

there is a lock file exist bellow folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi.manager\

I have enabled security and given admin user id password in RAD.
Just FYI, I have 2 admin accounts. rama and db2admin. I am using rama as admin user.

Can you please help me to fix this issue.
Much appropriated.

Thanks

Rama

Thanks for your help.

Comment: While creating profile, Windows service enabled. So I can start server form Service from Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools. It help resolve my issue. If Windows service disabled when creating profile?

Answer (score 0):

While creating profile, Windows service enabled. So I can start server form Service from Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools. It help resolved my issue.